# Transaction emails are not working after installing 6788 security patch in magento

Tags: security, email, magento, patch, transactional

I installed 6788 security patch to magento 1.9.1.0. now every function works properly. But transnational emails are not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Is your cron enabled? Do you use AOE_Scheduler? Did you patch it?

Comment: yes patch installed. i dont know about cron or AOE

Answer (score 0):

The main issue introduced in SUPEE-6788 that affected CMS and transactional emails was the requirement for Variables and Blocks to be registered in a whitelist in order to be used.

Check the emails for custom blocks/variables, add them to the whitelist. The Whitelist is found under System => Permissions => Variables/Blocks

Comment: thanks. can you please explain  how to check the emails for custom blocks/variables??? i'm new for magento

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiasco Labs answer and add following to the white list.

**Variables:**

web/unsecure/base_url

web/secure/base_url

trans_email/ident_support/name

trans_email/ident_support/email

trans_email/ident_general/name

trans_email/ident_general/email

trans_email/ident_sales/name

trans_email/ident_sales/email

trans_email/ident_custom1/name

trans_email/ident_custom1/email

trans_email/ident_custom2/name

trans_email/ident_custom2/email

general/store_information/name

general/store_information/phone

general/store_information/address

**Blocks:**

```
core/template
catalog/product_new
enterprise_catalogevent/event_lister (in Magento Enterprise Edition)
```

Refer following link:

[SUPEE-6788 Technical Details](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)